# Disable bootstrap for one element

Tags: css, class, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to achieve is to disable the Twitter Bootstrap class for my own input element with class named `login_button`. By default the `bootstrap.min.css` class is adding unnecessary properties like `box-shadow` etc. to my `input.login_button` element.

I know I can define `box-shadow: none;` but I wonder if there are other possibilities to achieve that?

Comment: give it a different class name and set your own properties

Comment: @lbu Bootstrap does selector `input[type="text"]` it doesnt select element by class. I got my own class already but bootstrap is still overriding.

Comment: and you can override it too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just override the Bootstrap style. As long as Bootstrap is included on your page before your custom CSS then your CSS should override Bootstrap as the specificity of the selector would be the same. Add this to your custom CSS and override the styles accordingly:

```css
input.login_button {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    line-height: initial;
    /* Etc. */
}
```

Here `input.login_button` has a [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) score of `011` whereas Bootstrap's `input[type="text"]` only has a specificity score of `010`, meaning your custom style will be strong enough to override Bootstrap's regardless of the order of your CSS.

Answer (score 8):

You can't, except by modifying bootstrap.min.css. All you can do is overwrite the styles with more specific selectors.

Comment: From what you said I guess I can use the `:not(.login_button)` on the bootstrap's selector? Is the `:not:` selector only available in CSS3?

Answer (score 1):

***Solution***

The Easiest Solution in this case is that you can write `!important` with you own custom CSS lines and that will prevent  bootstrap from adding any unintended styles.