# Removing bootstrap styling from certain elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created mockups of elements with precise css styling.
They work great! But I want to incorporate them into a bootstrap site.
When they happens, they lose all the nice looking styling I've made:

- Is there a way to **not use** bootstrap css on certain classes within a bootstrap site?

For example, here's the item with and without bootstrap:

with bootstrap:

```css
.pkmn-pc {
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pkmn-summary, .pkmn-info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
}

.pkmn-summary {
  width: 193px;
  background: #745fb5;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #745fb5, #9a6dbb);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.pkmn-summary:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    left: -182px;
    bottom: -31px;
    height: 5px;
    background: green;
    /**width: 73%;**/
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.pkmn-summary:after {
  width: 73%;
}

.pkmn-info {
  background: #333538;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pkmn-outer {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.pkmn-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3px;
}

.pkmn-sprite {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pkmn-name {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.pkmn-lvl {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  display: block;
}

.crown {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="pkmn-pc">
  <div class="pkmn-summary">
      <img class="pkmn-sprite" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/e/ea/113MS.png" />
  <code class="pkmn-name">15Characterssss</code>
  </div>
  <div class="pkmn-info">
  <img class="crown" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" />
    <div class="pkmn-outer">
      <img class="heart" src="https://image.ibb.co/kB8vi6/heart.png">
      <div class="pkmn-inner"></div>
      <img class="star" src="https://image.ibb.co/e7w4bR/Shiny_VIStar.png">
    </div>
    <code class="pkmn-lvl">lvl 100</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

without bootstrap

```css
.pkmn-pc {
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pkmn-summary, .pkmn-info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
}

.pkmn-summary {
  width: 193px;
  background: #745fb5;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #745fb5, #9a6dbb);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.pkmn-summary:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    left: -182px;
    bottom: -31px;
    height: 5px;
    background: green;
    /**width: 73%;**/
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.pkmn-summary:after {
  width: 73%;
}

.pkmn-info {
  background: #333538;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pkmn-outer {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.pkmn-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3px;
}

.pkmn-sprite {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pkmn-name {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.pkmn-lvl {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  display: block;
}

.crown {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pkmn-pc">
  <div class="pkmn-summary">
      <img class="pkmn-sprite" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/e/ea/113MS.png" />
  <code class="pkmn-name">15Characterssss</code>
  </div>
  <div class="pkmn-info">
  <img class="crown" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" />
    <div class="pkmn-outer">
      <img class="heart" src="https://image.ibb.co/kB8vi6/heart.png">
      <div class="pkmn-inner"></div>
      <img class="star" src="https://image.ibb.co/e7w4bR/Shiny_VIStar.png">
    </div>
    <code class="pkmn-lvl">lvl 100</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

thanks!

Comment: You can override bootstrap styles with the `!important` rule but I would use it sparingly.

Comment: @MasterYoda not really a good advice to use `!important`, rather add a class to make it more specific css selectors to your override.

Comment: @MasterYoda even though it would work, it can get messy really fast. It's better to use the order of CSS selectors to change layout, than to override with `!important` .

Comment: @mint you can add your custom css to the class you declared as `pkmn-name`

Comment: @Dejan.S thats why I said to use it **sparingly**.  I never told OP to use it anywhere they feel like using it.

Comment: @MasterYoda I didn't consider using !important, but that's mostly because I don't want to override the bootstrap styles per se, I want to negate them completely (so I don't have any styles to override them with but the defaults, if that makes sense)

Comment: @mint You cant do that as Bootstrap has already applied css to those elements. All you can do is override the bootstrap css either using the !Important rule OR by loading your own customised stylesheet after bootstrap has loaded and specifically modifying each style that was applied by Bootstrap. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414777/disable-bootstrap-for-one-element

Comment: @MasterYoda ah, I understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit some of your existing css to overwrite bootstrap css

```css
.pkmn-pc {
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pkmn-summary, .pkmn-info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
}

.pkmn-summary {
  width: 193px;
  background: #745fb5;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #745fb5, #9a6dbb);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.pkmn-summary:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    left: -197px;
    bottom: -35px;
    height: 5px;
    background: green;
    /**width: 73%;**/
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.pkmn-summary:after {
  width: 73%;
}

.pkmn-info {
  background: #333538;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pkmn-outer {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.pkmn-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3px;
}

.pkmn-sprite {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pkmn-name {
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: white;
}

.pkmn-lvl {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}

.crown {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="pkmn-pc">
  <div class="pkmn-summary">
      <img class="pkmn-sprite" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/e/ea/113MS.png" />
  <code class="pkmn-name">15Characterssss</code>
  </div>
  <div class="pkmn-info">
  <img class="crown" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" />
    <div class="pkmn-outer">
      <img class="heart" src="https://image.ibb.co/kB8vi6/heart.png">
      <div class="pkmn-inner"></div>
      <img class="star" src="https://image.ibb.co/e7w4bR/Shiny_VIStar.png">
    </div>
    <code class="pkmn-lvl">lvl 100</code>
  </div>
</div>
```