# How Can I disable Bootstrap Functions for a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div and I want to disable all bootstrap css on that.

```
<p class="bootstrap-off"></p>
```

I want disable All Bootstrap Functions For  elements that have '.bootstrap-off'

Comment: It depends on what styles you want to override.

Comment: That is not possible as long as bootstrap files are included in your html file. The only way you can do that is just to override any required styles for your div

Comment: I have a webpage with some css for nav and ul ,li,tooltip,... and when I add Bootstrap cdn to my code it changed elements even I add !important to my css but don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the Bootstrap Style for that elements CSS.

You can refer this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414777/disable-bootstrap-for-one-element?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

This is based off of [Meyer's reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). Place this at the beginning of the custom style sheet after you have added Bootstrap and it will reset the styling of any element with class 'bootstrap-off'. Bootstrap might have styles that are not reset by this, you can add them for whichever element.

```html
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

.bootstrap-off {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body-bootstrap-off {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol-bootstrp-off, ul-bootstrp-off {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote-bootstrap-off, q-bootstrap-off {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote-bootstrap-off:before, blockquote-bootstrap-off:after,
q-bootstrap-off:before, q-bootstrap-off:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table-bootstrap-off {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type style in inline mod 
        Eg:

tag style in bootstrap color green then inline css override it

```
       <p style="color:blue">this is paragraph</p>
```

Note: it is only possible for smaller changes. other wise change the bootstrap and use custom css